# Merge xml layout programmatically in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-inflate

I have build a layout programmatically in Android (a treeview) and now I'd like to add to the built view a topbar (topbar.xml).

So what I need is instead of:

```
setContentView(scroll)
```

Something like:

```
inflateInMyViewCalledScroll(topbar.xml)
setContentView(scroll)
```

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ScrollView can only have one direct child.

So you have to do something like this:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/foo" android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--  youll add topbar here, programmatically -->
        <other things/>
    </LinearLayout/>
</ScrollView>
```

And then at runtime, you'll inflate topbar

```
View topbar = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.topbar, null);
```

and add it as the first index in `foo`

```
foo.addView(topbar, 0);
```

Comment: I'm sorry to bother but your trick is causing me some problem. For example I can't find the resources I'm looking for (it's like the com.controller.R class haven't the specified resources). Moreover I don't want the topbar to be scrolled, I add a resource to the scroll that I want scrolled and I'd like to have the topbar fix at the top...

Comment: Ok I had a problem that I was able to fetch the layout but then I couldn't add to it other components. I created a new LinearLayout and added all to it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Inflate `topbar.xml` using `LayoutInflater`, putting the results into `scroll`:

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.topbar, scroll);
```

Comment: I already tried this but I get RuntimeException "unable to start Activity ..."

Comment: @LuigiTiburzi: When you examined the Java stack trace in LogCat associated with this exception, what did you learn?

Comment: It says scrollView can host only one direct child... but I need it to have a topbar...

Comment: @LuigiTiburzi: "It says scrollView can host only one direct child" -- correct. "but I need it to have a topbar" -- then you need the "topbar" and other stuff to be in some other container. See Matt's answer.